# Magento 2, overriding cookie module, domain name is not set correctly

Tags: magento2, cookie, website-restriction

As a requirement, the magento 2 EE website does not ask user to allow for setting cookie, it is set by default and it just notifies user by message. So I override the `vendor/magento/module-cookie/view/frontend/templates/html/notices.phtml` in custom template. I get everything set right except the `domain` value. Dot is missing.

Where in `vendor/magento/module-cookie` the domain is set with dot in begging? The value of domain supposed to be `.local.test.com` for sub domains.

[image]

Comment: it's not related to your issue but may be this url will help you: https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-cookie-notice.html